# JavaScript: Call function from child html document

Tags: javascript, html

What's the best way to execute a javascript function in a child html document?

In my parent doc, I have this:

```
function validate() {
        debugger;
        var firstName = frm.FirstName.value;
        var lastName = frm.LastName.value;
        var email = frm.Email.value;

        if (!validateFirstName(firstName)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!validateLastName(lastName)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!validateEmail(email)) {
            return false;
        }

        var disp = window.open("results.html");
        disp.window.setData(firstName, lastName, email, frm.Comments);

        if (disp.confirm("Is this information correct?")) {
            disp.close();
        }
    }
```

in the child doc (results.html), I have this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setData(firstName, lastName, email, comments) {
        frm.FirstName.value = firstName;
        frm.LastName.value = lastName;
        frm.Email.value = email;
        frm.Comments.value = comments;
    }
</script>
```

This is not working. Please tell me how I can do this with just plain javascript and html (no JQuery, etc).

Thanks

Comment: The .js function "setData()" in the second html document (child doc) which I want called after the parent doc's form is validated. It will set the data and the user will confirm whether OK or not. Note, this is not a real life problem (thankfully).. but is an unusual theoretical problem I have to solve for a course I am taking.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the **opener** property. it returns a reference to the window that created the window.

When opening a window with window.open(), you can use this property from the destination window to return details of the source (parent) window.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        function setData(firstName, lastName, email, comments) {
            opener.frm.FirstName.value = firstName;
            opener.frm.LastName.value = lastName;
            opener.frm.Email.value = email;
            opener.frm.Comments.value = comments;
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to set the values from the parent form to the child form. I tried this:  window.onload = function () {
  frm.FirstName.value = opener.frm.FirstName.value;  //etc....  but it didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: the variable `frm` references a `<form>` element in the child doc too?

Comment: yes. I could change the "frm" name to make it less confusing I guess.. but there are 2 frm elements.. 1 in the parent and 1 in the child.. both docs have the same layout as well.. only difference is child doc is readonly (it is a confirmation screen)

Comment: Ok, So in the child doc you can do: `window.onload = function () { var childFrm = document.getElementById("theIdOfYourChildForm"); childFrm.FirstName.value = opener.frm.FirstName.value; //etc`

Comment: Sorry that doesn't work.. but don't worry; I've taken a different approach: `var disp = window.open("", "results");` and then I used `disp.document.write("<html><body><h2>`...etc.. so it's not ideal.. but it works and it will get me through the practical exam (if that comes up). Thanks anyway for trying.

Comment: NOTE: You didn't solve the problem, but the info was useful, so I've upvoted you. Thanks for your time.  :)

Comment: if you can post your code on jsfiddle.net, so i will take a look and try to solve your problem, because i can't understand why it doesn't work.